# Open Office and JODConverter export word document to html

Tags: java, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I use Open Office and JODConverter to export word documents to html and I would like to ask if -apart from the page number- there is other format information that is lost

Comment: Did you try reading the user manuals of these applications?

Comment: I had a look at the user's manual of OO, but I was not able to find something. Have you found something that might be helpful?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, just trying to make sure you weren't going on a long needless search. Sorry :(